# Error: While creating partitions in SSAS Cube

Tags: ssas

While creating Partitions in SSAS Cubes, I am getting an error stating `"Errors related to feature availability and configuration: Exceeded the maximum number of partitions in a measure group.`

Because of requirement, I need to create minimum 5 partitions. Please Help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to two similar problems I have found:

1. You use a AnalysisServer-Version that does not feature multiple partitions (Standard)

Check your SQLServer Version if it fits the required features or install the Enterprise one / Developer Core. If you use Visualstudio - BI Tools, check the BuildTab if the Server Version is correctly inserted there as well or change it.

You find more Information [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f58f62a4-9630-4ea5-8ffd-c3e99cda498d/processing-a-cube-dimension?forum=sqlanalysisservices)

2. You use more than 1 writeback-Partition in a measuregroup

I could not find why there is this limit, but I guess it is not in the intention to split a measuregroup into multiple Partitions, instead use multiple measuregroups to partition them fully, as they all share same dependencies.

You need to make sure you only have one writeback partition in a measuregroup, as stated [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/09c1e8e0-e3d5-4205-8e2f-0d5bfc1c9945/exceeded-the-maximum-number-of-partitions-in-a-measure-group?forum=sqlanalysisservices)

If those two possible solutions did not help you, you should consider posting in Microsofts SSAS Forum, as there are many experts luring around helping you further with this quite special topic [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/home?forum=sqlanalysisservices)